# Show Year([Year]) as two digits in calculated data type

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

When I use `Year([Year])` in a calculated datatype field, it shows the year like 2018.

I want to show the year in 2 digits like 18 for 2018.
Can anyone suggest me how I can print 2 digits year in a calculated datatype field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access, use a query. Avoid calculated fields by all means:

```
Select *, Format([YourDateField],"yy") As TwoDigitYear
From YourTable
```

This will return a leading zero as well.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you may use `SUBSTRING` & `CAST` functions

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS varchar(4)),3,2)
```

put your date instead of `GETDATE()`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(YEAR('01-01-2018') AS varchar(4)),3,2)
```

Same in ms access with `RIGHT` function